# String manipulation complexity

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, .net-2.0

I have been programming for one year and I have done `string` manipulation many times but never understood how it actually works or what the best way of doing it.

Let's say I have this string

```
String abc = "https://uu2020.devuueva.com/portal/mesddsa/usforeer/nance/tings/M3C102d4104/1007/tingjack/default.aspx";
```

I want to only this part

```
"https://uu2020.devuueva.com/portal/mesddsa/usforeer/nance/tings/M3C102d4104"
```

Characters/Names can change and are dynamic, however "/" isn't. Can someone demonstrate the simplest and the best way of doing it.

Comment: "String manipulation" covers a **huge** area of possibility, using both inbuilt string functions, and also things like regular expressions. What you're asking here makes little sense, because you have not given us any "rules" that the manipulation is supposed to follow

Comment: You mean, you would break the string on the 9th `/`?

Comment: @fdgfdgsdfg When talking about string manipulation, I would mostly pick *regular expressions*. However, they have a price (processing and maintenance). For your case, the easier way is the most straightforward: count the backslashes and get a `substring`

Comment: @AndreCalil When i try to Use SubString it asks for two Int parameters :S

Comment: @fdgfdgs dfg Did you try reading the docs for `substring` function? It explains what these " two Int parameters" are.

Comment: Can you tell us which version of the framework you're using? This'll stop us guessing which Linq methods we can or cant use!!

Comment: For future reference, tagging questions with the right framework can help get correct answers - especially in your case where you're using quite an old one. Have tagged this question for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to bear in mind here, is that if you're dealing with a Uri, you are better off using the `Uri` class to extract pieces of information than trying to string-mash a solution together.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

For example:

```
var part = String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",uri.Scheme,uri.Authority, String.Join("",uri.Segments.Take(7)));
```

Gets the section you're after. Live example: http://rextester.com/JRWKOG58567

---

**EDIT**

Having discovered some more requirement, and frameework limitation, you might be better string mashing this after all, but you can still leverage some functionality from the `Uri` class.

```
var input = "https://uu2020.devuueva.com/portal/mesddsa/usforeer/nance/tings/M3C102d4104/1007/tingjack/default.aspx";
var uri = new Uri(input);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("{0}://{1}/",uri.Scheme,uri.Authority);

var parts = uri.PathAndQuery.Split(new char[]{'/'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    sb.AppendFormat("/{0}",parts[i])   ;
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/HBK80648

Comment: I am getting it from Database, and need to get part of it to execute a stored procedure to get some other information from DB

Comment: for string.join function it says   can't convert IENumerable <> to []

Comment: @fdgfdgsdfg - Older versions of the framework didnt have that overload of `String.Join`, so you need to turn the segments to an array. Therefore `String.Join("",uri.Segments.Take(7).ToArray())`

Comment: when I use the code, it gives me what I want but it ends with "/" which isn't the requirement, should I remove it using  ".remove" or if there is a better way

Comment: I can't use "Take" function either

Answer (score 2):

```
 var t="https://uu2020.devuueva.com/portal/mesddsa/usforeer/nance/tings/M3C102d4104/1007/tingjack/default.aspx";
     string[] g= t.Split('/');
     var h=String.Join("/", g.Where((i,n)=>n<9).ToArray());
    Console.write( h);
```

result : `https://uu2020.devuueva.com/portal/mesddsa/usforeer/nance/tings/M3C102d4104`

Comment: which assembly are we suppose to use for "Dumb()" function

Comment: @fdgfdgsdfg You can combine it to one line , but I seperated to be more clear.

Comment: getting exception for  "Where" is not defined in System.Array, I guess I am using older version, is there any alternative available ?